# CLIPS incrementing variable without endless loop

Tags: infinite-loop, clips, expert-system

I would greatly appreciate some assistance with my CLIPS project.

Okay so I'm attempting to create a dog breed adviser. The deftemplate looks like this:

```
(deftemplate breed
     (multislot name)
     (slot size)
     (slot type-owner)
     (slot Living_Space)
     (slot children)
     (slot grooming)
     (slot exercise)
     (slot noisiness)
     (slot trainability)
     (slot aggression)
     (slot playfulness)
     (slot excitability)
     (slot score))
```

A deffacts looks like this:

```
(deffacts dog-breeds
(breed (name Great_Dane)
       (size 5)
       (type-owner No)
       (Living_Space 5)
       (children 5) 
       (grooming 1)
       (exercise 4)
       (noisiness 2)
       (trainability 1)
       (aggression 2)
       (playfulness 2)
       (excitability 3)
       (score 0))
```

So I write two types of defrules: one retracts facts that do not meet the (user specified) criteria and the other type increments the "score" value every time the fact meets the criteria.  Only a few rules retract, so it's important for me to get the increment rules working. The user input and criteria for each slot can be from 1 to 5.

My question is: how do I change the following code without going into an infinite loop?  At the end I want to seek out the fact with the maximum score and display it.

```
(defrule children
(input 1)
?children <- (breed (name ?)(size ?)(type-owner ?)(Living_Space  ?)   (children 1|2)(grooming ?)(exercise ?)(noisiness ?)
(trainability ?)(aggression ?)(playfulness ?)(excitability ?)(score  ?score)
=>  
(bind ?sc (+ ?score 1))
(modify ?children (score ?sc))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the sole purpose of the (input 1) fact is to increment the score and is no longer needed after the score is incremented, just retract that fact.

```
(defrule children
   ?f <- (input 1)
   ?children <- (breed (children 1|2) (score ?score))
   =>
   (retract ?f)  
   (bind ?sc (+ ?score 1))
   (modify ?children (score ?sc)))
```

Note that I've removed all of the slots from the pattern containing the ? wildcard as these are unnecessary.

If the (input 1) fact is  needed by other rules, you can create an intermediate fact that can be retracted.

```
(defrule create-intermediate
   (input 1)
   => 
   (assert (increment)))

(defrule children
   ?f <- (increment)
   ?children <- (breed (children 1|2) (score  ?score))
   =>
   (retract ?f)  
   (bind ?sc (+ ?score 1))
   (modify ?children (score ?sc)))
```

You could also track what you've scored within the fact. Add a (multislot scored) to your breed deftemplate and then you can do this:

```
(defrule children
   (input 1)
   ?children <- (breed (children 1|2) (score ?score) (scored $?scored))
   (test (not (member$ children ?scored)))
   =>
   (bind ?sc (+ ?score 1))
   (modify ?children (score ?sc) (scored children ?scored)))
```

Finally, object patterns do not retrigger when slots are changed that are not present in the pattern. So if you used defclasses instead of deftemplates, you could do this:

```
(defrule children
   (input 1)
   ?children <- (object (is-a BREED) (children 1|2))
   =>
   (bind ?sc (+ (send ?children get-score) 1))
   (send ?children put-score ?sc))
```